# Do I have to show that elements of $L$ commutes with elements of $N$ (like in case of direct product) and if so, why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules, exact-sequence, module-isomorphism

I want to prove the following $a \Longleftrightarrow d$ in the following questoin:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. For $R-$modules $L,M,N$ show that the following conditions are equivalent.(all functions are $R-$ module homomorphisms.)

a- $M \cong_{R} L \oplus N.$

b- There exists a left-split short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow{L} \rightarrow{M} \rightarrow{N} \rightarrow{0.}$ (i.e., $\exists$ a retraction )

c- There exists a right-split short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow{L} \rightarrow{M} \rightarrow{N} \rightarrow{0.}$ (i.e., $\exists$ a section )

d- $L$ and $N$ are $R-$submodules of $M,$ $L + N = M$ and $L \cap N = \{0\}. $

**My trial is:**

$a \implies d$

This follows directly from the definition of direct sum.

$d \implies a$

We will prove this in the following $2$ steps:

1-$d \implies b.$

**Proof:**

Assume that  $L$ and $N$ are $R-$submodules of $M,$ $L + N = M$ and $L \cap N = \{0\},$ and we want to show that there exists a left-split short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow{L} \rightarrow{M} \rightarrow{N} \rightarrow{0.}$ (i.e., $\exists$ a retraction )

Given $m \in M,$ by hypothesis there exist $l \in L$ and $n \in N$ with $m = l + n$ and $L \cap N = \{0\}.$

If also $m = a + b$ for $a \in L$ and $b \in N,$ then $l + n = a +b,$and so $a - l = n - b$ where $(a - l) \in L$ and $(n - b) \in  N$ because $L$ and $N$ are modules. But then $(a-l), (n-b) \in L \cap N = \{0\}.$ Which means that $a - l = 0$ and $n - b = 0,$ hence $l = a$ and $n = b.$ Therefore, $l$ and $n$ are uniquely determined by the choice of $m.$

Let $i: L \rightarrow M $ be the inclusion homomorphism. Define $r: M \rightarrow L$ and $p: M \rightarrow N$ by $r(l + n) = l$ and $p(l+n) = n.$

**Proving that $r$ and $p$ are homomorphisms.**

**First.**

a- Given $a,l \in L$ and $b,,n \in N,$ we have:

$r((l + n) + (a + b)) = r((l + a) + (n + b)) = (l + a) = r(l + n) + r(a + b)$

b- Given $r' \in R$ and $m\in M,$ then we have:

$r(r'm) = r(r'(l+n)) = r((r'l + r'n)) = r'l = r'r((l + n)).$

**Second.**

a- Given $a,l \in L$ and $b,,n \in N,$ we have:

$p((l + n) + (a + b)) = p((l + a) + (n + b)) = (n + b) = p((l + n)) + p((a + b))$

b- Given $r' \in R$ and $m\in M,$ then we have:

$p(r'm) = p(r'(l+n)) = p((r'l + r'n)) = r'n = r'p((l + n)).$

So, $r$ and $p$ are $R-$module homomorphisms.

**Proving that $\operatorname{ker} p = \operatorname{im} i.$**

$p(m) = p((l+n)) = n = 0_{N}$ iff $m = l \in L.$ So, $\operatorname{ker} p = L + 0_N = i(L).$ Therefore the sequence $$0 \longrightarrow L \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} M \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} N \longrightarrow 0$$ is exact.

Moreover, $r$ is a retraction because $(r \circ i)(l) = r(i(l)) = r((l + 0_N)) = l$ i.e.$(r \circ i) = id_L$ as required.

2-$b \Longleftrightarrow a.$  (proved previously)

Then from $1$ and $2$ the required is proved.

**My questions are:**

1- Is my proof correct?

2- Do I have to show that elements of $L$ commutes with elements of $N$ (like in case of direct product) and if so, why?

3- When should I take the element of $M$ as an ordered pair and when should I take it as addition of two elements in $L$ and $N$?

Could anyone help me answer these questions please?

**EDIT**

My answers to my questions:

1- I guess yes.

2- I guess no because addition is commutative.

3- I do not know the answer to this.

Are my answers to myself correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that $M \cong L \oplus N$ implies that $L$ and $N$ are submodules of $M$. I suggest you to change $(d)$'s statement to something like:

> $(d)$ There exists submodules $L' \cong L$ and $N' \cong N$ of $M$ such that $M = L'+N'$ and $L' \cap N' = 0$.

Now, to prove $(a) \!\!\implies\!\! (d)$, consider an isomorphism $\phi : L \oplus N \to M$ and take $L' = \{\phi(l,0) : l \in L\}$ and $N' = \{\phi(0,n) : n \in N\}$. On the other hand, to prove $(d) \!\!\implies\!\! (a)$ consider the map $\phi : L' \oplus N' \to M$ given by $\phi(l,n) = l+n$, and conclude that $M \cong L' \oplus N' \cong L \oplus N$.

So, since you already done $(a) \!\!\iff\!\! (b)$ and $(a) \!\!\iff\!\! (c)$, you already have the difficult (and interesting) parts.

Comment: So, can you criticize my proof of $d \implies a$ and tell me the issues in it please?

Comment: @hard Right, I forgot to mention that your proof of $(d) \!\!\implies\!\! (b)$ is correct. On the other hand, you have to take advantage of what we already know and what you have proved before. The only problem that I see is that $(a) \!\!\implies\!\! (d)$ is not true as the problem is written :)

Comment: What about my questions? can you answer them for me please?

Comment: 2) No, you don't have to prove that the elements of $N$ commutes with all the elements of $L$, your proof is perfectly fine. 3) The only elements that are ordered pairs is for the direct sum, since $L \oplus N$ is $L \times N$ equipped with the pointwise operations.

Comment: Do I have to add any details to your proof of $a\implies d$? like how can I prove that $L' \cap N' = \{ 0 \}$?

Comment: If $m$ is an element of $L' \cap N'$, then $m = \phi(l,0)$ and $m = \phi(0,n)$ for some $l \in L$ and $n \in N$, so $0 = m-m = \phi(l,0)-\phi(0,n) = \phi(l,-n)$. What does tell you the injectivity of $\phi$?

Comment: It tells me that each of $l$ and $n$ are zeros. :)

Comment: Can you please give me an example to show that $a \implies d$ is not correct in my statement of the question?

Comment: Sure! For example, $R^3 \cong R^2 \oplus R$ via the map $(r_1,r_2,r_3) \mapsto ((r_1,r_2),r_3)$, but $R^2$ and $R$ are not submodules of $R^3$, they can be *identified* as a submodules of $R^3$ since $R^2 \cong \{(r_1,r_2,0) : r_1,r_2 \in R\}$ and $R \cong \{(0,0,r) : r \in R\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!